# Can I block HTML elements from popular websites system-wide?

Tags: html, macos, ads, hosts

I know there is a hosts file that allows me to block entire domains.

```
0.0.0.0 blockthissite.net
::      blockthssite.net
```

I'd like to block particular elements for a website.

I can do this today with one of a variety of ad blocking tools, like uBlock Origin. It will only work on the browser that I set up the rule with for the ad blocking tool and, even then, it's really easy for someone to get around the rule by disabling the extension.

Is there a hosts file or something more system-wide that I can do to block HTML elements on my Mac?

For instance, I'd like to block the footer page on this popular website from every browser.

```
www.amazon.com###navFooter
```

Comment: This would be difficult. Not every request is HTML and not all HTML is in the DOM at the end of the request, navFooter might be made by JS. Would you want your email client (outlook/thunderbird) to block the element as well? What about looking at the raw HTML code? Would you expect it to not be there? This is a very broad ask and there is not really a way to cleanly do what you are asking for, that's why it is typically done at the rendering layer, in a browser, through an extension.

Comment: It sounds like this could be very difficult. What if I reduced the scope to blocking only HTML-snippets, excluding anything made by JS, and doing it only in browsers?

Comment: Possibly something like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/rewrite/) might let you get to where you want.  You can intercept network traffic and rewrite parts of the request/response.

Comment: AdGuard for Mac lets you write your own custom rules and blocks them system wide, it may cover your needs https://adguard.com/en/adguard-mac/overview.html

Comment: Hmm.. I tried AdGuard but the rules wouldn't stick. I would have to set the same rule again and again.